# UIbutton gets programmatically added on rotation

Tags: ios, rotation, uibutton

I am adding a `UIButton` to a view and when I rotate the device, one more button gets added on the screen. I need only one button and I do not want the second one to get added on rotation. 
I tried setting autoresizing masks as well for that button but it did not work as expected. I used the following code:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[button setFrame:bFrame];   
[self addSubview:button];
```

Comment: where are you adding this snippet?

Comment: Where is this piece of code being executed, is it in viewDidLoad or any custom method. Throw some more light.

Comment: In one of the custom methods this peace of code executes to create button on my view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to assume that the code you provided is executed upon orientation change.

What you want to do is to store the button in an instance variable and check if that variable is nil or not when the orientation is changed.

```
if (!button) {
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [button setFrame:bFrame];   
    [self addSubview:button];
}
```

This assumes that the variable `button` is an instance variable of the `UIView` or `UIViewController` and not a variable that's only in the scope of the method.

Regarding your `autoresizingMask`, please explain what you expected to happen and what actually happened in order for us to help you.

Comment: I have no clue if the value for button.autoresizingMask make any sense or not. I intended to keep button at its original location which is set via frame.

Comment: The value makes perfect sense. Try playing around with them to see if you understand them correctly (for example, I don't think you'd want it to have flexible margins on all sides). Does the rest of my answer make sense?